Two instances of Netatalk after upgrade Ubuntu Server 18.04 to 20.04
I have Two instance after upgrade
/usr/sbin/netatalk
and /usr/local/sbin/netatalk
For now second one is working after restoring from backup library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent-2.1.so.6.0.2
but it seems to me that it doesn't work quite smoothly.
Next problem is SMB, which one working read only :-(
